# Django: ManytoMany w/ extra fields gives back duplicate key error on .create()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the following code to create a new entry in my model:

```
ContactRelation.objects.create(
    lead=True, event=request.event, contact=contact
)
```

However, I am always running into that error message:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "contacts_contactrelation_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(14) already exists.

I expected Django to count up pk by itself. pk=14 already exists. If I write,

```
ContactRelation.objects.create(
    pk=199, lead=True, event=request.event, contact=contact
)
```

then my entry is successfully created. `ContactRelation` acts as many-to-many relationship table with [extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Do you understand why Django is dealing with `pks` that way?

```
class ContactRelation(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Stores data about individual events the contact interacted with.

    :param event: ForeignKey to the event.
    :type organizer: Event
    :param contact: ForeignKey to the contact.
    :type contact: Contact
    :param lead: If true, contact used the sign up form.
    :type lead: bool
    :param attendee: Contact assigned to ticket as attendee.
    :type attendee: bool
    :param purchaser: Contact made an order for the respective event.
    :type purchaser: bool
    """

    event = models.ForeignKey(
        'events.Event', related_name='contact_relation', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact, related_name='contact_relation', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    lead = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Lead', default=False
    )  # Contact who 'Signed Up'
    attendee = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Attendee', default=False
    )  # Contact assigned to ticket
    purchaser = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name='Purchaser', default=False
    )  # Contact made the order

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['event', 'contact']]
```

Comment: Have you figured it out?